# Transform UILabel around is axis horizontally in Swift

Tags: ios, uilabel, swift4, cgaffinetransform

is it possible to rotate UILabel around Its axis horizontally ? Something like flip clock ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean around it's axis horizontally? Which axis? Please create an image showing what you mean exactly and add what problems you are having with your current approach along with your code.

Comment: I mean something like digits in this clock https://youtu.be/MqsbGCUmKhc

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try this:

```
label.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i’m looking for. I want something without changing X.

Answer (score 0):

You might add a UILabel subclass, amd implement the flipping animation, like such:

```
@implementation FlippingLabel

- (void)flipToAlphabet:(NSString *)alphabet {
    [UIView transitionWithView:self
                      duration:0.3
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations: ^{
                        self.text = [self.text nextCharacterInSequence];
                    }
                    completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                        if (![self.text isEqualToString:alphabet]) {
                            if (![[self.text nextCharacterInSequence] isEqualToString:@"-"]) {
                                [self flipToAlphabet:alphabet];
                            }
                        }
                    }];
}
```

I did something similar in one of my previous projects.
https://github.com/mehul90/Flipper

Comment: Thanks, i will try this in swift. What is a nextCharacterInSequence ?